# CameraPosition zoom and target doesn't work in Android 6

Tags: java, android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm doing an app that show some POI on the map after reading a json with this points.
my app work well in android 4.4 but when I run it in android 6 (both emulator and real device), the camera does not zoom at the level I'm setting.
I'm receiving no errors or warning about some deprecated command.

this is the code in the MainActivity

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

        mapVar = map;
        // MapWrapperLayout initialization


        final MapWrapperLayout mapWrapperLayout = (MapWrapperLayout) findViewById(R.id.map_relative_layout);
        // MapWrapperLayout initialization

        mapWrapperLayout.init(map, getPixelsFromDp(this, 39 + 20));
        this.infoWindow = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window, null);
        this.infoTitle = (TextView) infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.title);
        this.infoSnippet = (TextView) infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.snippet);
        this.infoButton = (Button) infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.button);

        // Setting custom OnTouchListener which deals with the pressed state
        // so it shows up
        this.infoButtonListener = new OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener(infoButton,
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_but_green_sel), //btn_default_normal_holo_light
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_but_red_sel)) //btn_default_pressed_holo_light
        {


            @Override
            protected void onClickConfirmed(View v, Marker marker) {


                // Here we can perform some action triggered after clicking the button
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, marker.getTitle() + "'s button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, dettaglio.class);
                //EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
                String titolo = marker.getTitle();
                String idPOI = allMarkersMapIds.get(marker);
                String IMGPOI = allMarkersMapImg.get(marker);
                String Desc = allMarkersMapDesc.get(marker);
                String  idUtentePOI = allMarkersMapidUtente.get(marker);
                String  idCategoria = allMarkersMapidCategoria.get(marker);

                LATLON = marker.getPosition();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putParcelable("coordinatePOI", LATLON);
                intent.putExtra("bundle", args);

                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, titolo);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ID, idPOI);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_IMG, IMGPOI);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_Desc, Desc);
                intent.putExtra("IDCATEGORIAPOI", idCategoria);
                intent.putExtra("IDUTENTEPOI", idUtentePOI);


                startActivity(intent);

            }
        };
        this.infoButton.setOnTouchListener(infoButtonListener);


        map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                // Setting up the infoWindow with current's marker info
                infoTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
                infoSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());
                infoButtonListener.setMarker(marker);

                // We must call this to set the current marker and infoWindow references
                // to the MapWrapperLayout
                mapWrapperLayout.setMarkerWithInfoWindow(marker, infoWindow);
                return infoWindow;
            }
        });

/// HERE I CENTER AND ZOOM THE CAMERA
        CameraPosition googlePlex = CameraPosition.builder()
                .target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                .zoom(15)
                .bearing(0)
                .tilt(45)
                .build();

        setUpMapIfNeeded(0, ricercaString);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(googlePlex));
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(googlePlex), 2000, null);


    }
```

and I'm doing the same thing inside a service that listen for location changes

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    listPOI = MainActivity.getArrayList();
    // a bool value to understand if I can go ahead
    goAhead = MainActivity.getGoAhead();
    namesPOI = MainActivity.getNamePOI();
    range = PrefActivity.getRange();
    proximity = PrefActivity.getProximity();




    //checks whether the user wants to be notified
    if(proximity) {
    //check if the list of near POI is loaded
        if (goAhead) {

            if (utility.isNear(location, listPOI, namesPOI, range)) {
                POI = utility.getNamePOI();
                String msg = "You're near " + POI;
                tts1.tts.speak(msg, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

            }

        }
    }
    getLocation();




    CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()));
    MainActivity.mapVar.moveCamera(center);
    CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);
    MainActivity.mapVar.animateCamera(zoom);


}
```

But the zoom is still at world level...somebody can figure out why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I changed the onMapReady as follows, and now it work.

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

        mapVar = map;
        // MapWrapperLayout initialization


       CameraPosition googlePlex = CameraPosition.builder()
                .target(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                .zoom(15)
                .bearing(0)
                .tilt(45)
                .build();
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(googlePlex), 2000, null);


        final MapWrapperLayout mapWrapperLayout = (MapWrapperLayout) findViewById(R.id.map_relative_layout);
        // MapWrapperLayout initialization

        mapWrapperLayout.init(map, getPixelsFromDp(this, 39 + 20));
        this.infoWindow = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window, null);
        this.infoTitle = (TextView) infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.title);
        this.infoSnippet = (TextView) infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.snippet);
        this.infoButton = (Button) infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.button);

        // Setting custom OnTouchListener which deals with the pressed state
        // so it shows up
        this.infoButtonListener = new OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener(infoButton,
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_but_green_sel), //btn_default_normal_holo_light
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_but_red_sel)) //btn_default_pressed_holo_light
        {


            @Override
            protected void onClickConfirmed(View v, Marker marker) {


                // Here we can perform some action triggered after clicking the button
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, marker.getTitle() + "'s button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, dettaglio.class);
                //EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
                String titolo = marker.getTitle();
                String idPOI = allMarkersMapIds.get(marker);
                String IMGPOI = allMarkersMapImg.get(marker);
                String Desc = allMarkersMapDesc.get(marker);
                String  idUtentePOI = allMarkersMapidUtente.get(marker);
                String  idCategoria = allMarkersMapidCategoria.get(marker);

                LATLON = marker.getPosition();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putParcelable("coordinatePOI", LATLON);
                intent.putExtra("bundle", args);

                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, titolo);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ID, idPOI);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_IMG, IMGPOI);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_Desc, Desc);
                intent.putExtra("IDCATEGORIAPOI", idCategoria);
                intent.putExtra("IDUTENTEPOI", idUtentePOI);


                startActivity(intent);

            }
        };
        this.infoButton.setOnTouchListener(infoButtonListener);


        map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                // Setting up the infoWindow with current's marker info
                infoTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
                infoSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());
                infoButtonListener.setMarker(marker);

                // We must call this to set the current marker and infoWindow references
                // to the MapWrapperLayout
                mapWrapperLayout.setMarkerWithInfoWindow(marker, infoWindow);
                return infoWindow;
            }
        });



        setUpMapIfNeeded(0, ricercaString);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }

map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    }
```

Comment: why you are doing it twice?

Comment: Hi, I can't remember now, later I will see the code  and I will let you know

Comment: okay. `CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(place).zoom(15).bearing(0).tilt(45).build();` this isn't working for me. Check at your end once. let me know if I need to change anything

Comment: Hi Prabs, You're right, later  I have removed the second call to the CameraPosition, I can confirm you that my app works fine.
but I did a lot of more things, so the code can't be compared.
What's the issue you are retrieving?

Answer (score 0):

1.

Instead of `animateCamera` > `newCameraPosition` use `moveCamera` > `newLatLngZoom`

Replace

```
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(location).zoom(12).build();
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

with

`googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 9));`

2. Use `CancelableCallback` in `animateCamera` (kind of work around)
   .

   ```
       googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latLngBounds, 5), new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
           @Override
           public void onFinish() {

               CameraUpdate zout = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(-3f);
               googleMap.animateCamera(zout);
           }

           @Override
           public void onCancel() {

           }
       });
   ```